# Own exception class constructors

Tags: c#, .net, exception

In the article "Best Practices for Exceptions" (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/seyhszts(v=vs.110).aspx) I found following clause:

> In C# and C++, use at least the three common constructors when
>   creating your own exception classes: the default constructor, a
>   constructor that takes a string message, and a constructor that takes
>   a string message and an inner exception.

Why I must define these three common constructors? My exception class is useless without additional custom properties, and I exactly should pass their values as parameters in my exception class constructor.

Comment: It's a best practice - noone tells you, that you _must_ do it.

Comment: If your exception needs other info then that's fine.  Best practices are just that; best practices, not requirements.  If you know that you need to do something different, then do something different.

Comment: What if someone wants to throw your exception with a custom message? Or wrapping another exception? Other than that like the others say, you can choose to do as you please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define those constructors because most developers will expect them to be there. There are a few patterns, like wrapping exceptions, that can only be done if you can specify an inner exception. These best practices ensures that you can always use those patterns. For instance:

```
try { ... }
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw new MyBusinessException(ex);
}
```

On the other side, this is not a must. If your exception builds its own message from a set of parameters, then there is no point it letting the user change it.